# ~/.aws/credentials から AWS_KEY と AWS_SECRET を抽出したい

Tags: aws, aws-cli

普段、aws を使って開発しているときは、 `aws configure` を用いて aws key の設定を行っています。結果、 `~/.aws/credentials` にそれらが保存されます。

この状態で、たとえば aws とインタラクションを行うサーバーの開発などをやっていたとします。それを docker に詰め込んだりなどします。サーバーの挙動を確認したくなります。

docker のコンテナは、環境変数から aws の鍵情報を読み込むのが自然かと思います。なので、それをコマンドから `docker run` する際には、どうにかして `~/.aws/credentials` の内容を読み込まなければならないと思っています。

#### 質問

`~/.aws/credentials` に書いてある特定の profile の AWS_KEY や AWS_SECRET を抽出するコマンドはありますか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws configure --profile PROFILE get aws_access_key_id
aws configure --profile PROFILE get aws_secret_access_key
```

でしょうか。

Comment: 補足として、 config ファイルに書かれてあるもののみが取得でき、例えば環境変数で設定されてあってもそれは読み込まれないことに注意です。 (`aws configure list` で key っぽいものが表示されても、 `aws configure get` で取得できるとは限らない)

Answer (score 0):

既に承認済みとのことですが、僕の対処法を書いておきます。参考に。

dockerコンテナ内にaws認証情報を環境変数なりで埋め込んで、コンテナ内からAWS SDKを実行したい場合がありました。

以下対策です。

1. ホストOSの`.bash_profile`に以下を追加して、環境変数に`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`を設定

   ```bash
   if [ -f ~/.aws/credentials ]; then export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(grep aws_access ~/.aws/credentials | cut -d" " -f 3); fi
   if [ -f ~/.aws/credentials ]; then export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(grep aws_secret ~/.aws/credentials | cut -d" " -f 3); fi
   ```
2. `docker run`時に環境変数を渡す。`docker-compose`であれば`environment`に`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`を宣言するだけ